# Crash with hardware acceleration of fragment transition animations

Tags: android, android-animation, hardware-acceleration, android-4.3-jelly-bean

I am using a slide-in / slide-out animation for fragment transitions. To smoothen out these animations I am using hardware acceleration by setting the layer type of the fragment to `View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE` before the animation and back to `View.LAYER_TYPE_NONE` if the animation is completed.

```
public Animation onCreateAnimation(int transit, boolean enter, int
        nextAnim) {
    if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 0) {
        return super.onCreateAnimation(transit, enter, nextAnim);
    }

    if (nextAnim == 0) {
        nextAnim = enter ? android.R.anim.slide_in_left :
                android.R.anim.slide_out_right;
    }
    Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(),
            nextAnim);

    // smoothening animations
    if (animation != null) {
        getView().setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
        animation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                if (getView() != null) {
                    getView().setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_NONE, null);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation arg0) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation arg0) {
            }
        });
    }
    return animation;
}
```

I recently discovered, that my app crashes randomly on some transitions only on some devices with `Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1)`. I could narrow down the error to the line where the layer-type is set to `HARDWARE`. If I set it to `NONE` or `SOFTWARE` everything works fine.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance for any help!

EDIT: This seems to be an Android 4.3-specific bug. These crashes can be reproduced on 4.3 devices and the 4.3 emulator (host-GPU enabled). It is fine on Android 4.1, 4.2.2 and 4.4.

I am disabling hardware acceleration for 4.3 as a workaround. Hardware acceleration is only needed on older devices with slower processing power in my use case - and these are very unlikely to have 4.3. But anyways, it would be nice if someone had an idea how this is really fixed.

Comment: Can you tell me how you can disable the hardware acceleration ?

Comment: Just found another wherearound : delete those lines getView().setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null) it works for me =)

Comment: Yeah, thats how I disabled hardware acceleration as far as I remember